# Determine Who Dropped a Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql

I have a SQL Server 2005 database that has been deleted, and I need to discover who deleted it. Is there a way of obtaining this user name?

Comment: Did you checked the sql logs?

Comment: @Evan,  This is NOT an ass-kicking exercise!  In my enlightened company, we will offer the offending user an intense period of 're-education'.  If that doesn't work, it time for the baseball bats...

Comment: +1 for using a cousin of a clue-by-four, still the most effective re-education process on the planet today.

Comment: @MagicAndi - Sorry-- just couldn't resist adding the tag after remembering it on the "Who dropped a table" question a couple of weeks back.  *smile*

Comment: If you want to pay for it, there are a couple of products (Apex Log is one) that will read the transaction log (or log backups) and get information like this back.

Comment: Is ass kicking really necessary?  While it was a bad mistake, it was a mistake. Restore the backup. If one doesn't have a backup, perhaps the ass kicking should be refocused in to a backup and recovery model...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not there in the default trace still, see my answer to kind-of this question on ServerFault a couple of weeks ago at [Is there any way to determine who dropped a table?](https://serverfault.com/questions/26902/is-there-anyway-to-determine-who-dropped-a-table). It links to a blog post I wrote for 2000, 2005, 2008 to find out when a table was dropped and who did it - you could adapt it for a database too. Checkout my blog post at [Finding out who dropped a table using the transaction log](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Finding-out-who-dropped-a-table-using-the-transaction-log.aspx).

Hope this helps!

PS Checkout DDL Triggers as a way to prevent this happening in future.

Answer (score 2):

You might check the Schema Changes History under Standard Reports.